# search with no acent won't work (autoComplete.js)

Tags: autocomplete.js

i would like to have response when i search a city but with no accent
exemple : search => "frejus"

autoComplete.js working with search => "fréjus" and give me results.

The api return response with some results and fréjus is in it when autocomplete.js call the api.

See code here => https://codepen.io/dimitri-basseguy/pen/dywMZoL

```
// https://adresse.data.gouv.fr/api-doc/adresse 
// config for api url
let banApiEndpoint = 'https://api-adresse.data.gouv.fr/';
let apiTypeSearch = 'municipality';
let apiResultLimit = 6;

const autoCompleteJS = new autoComplete({
  selector: '#location',
  // placeHolder: 'Recherchez une ville...',
  threshold: 3,
  
  data: {
    src: async (query) => {
      try {
        const source = await fetch(
          `${banApiEndpoint}search/?type=${apiTypeSearch}&autocomplete=1&limit=${apiResultLimit}&q=${query}`
        );
        const data = await source.json();
        
        return data.features.map((el) => {
                    // console.log(el);
          let _el = el.properties;
                    console.log(_el);
          _el.geometry = el.geometry;
                    // console.log(_el.geometry);
          return _el;
        });
      } catch (error) {
        return error;
      }
    },
    keys: ['label', 'postcode'],
  },

  resultsList: {
    element: (list, data) => {
      const info = document.createElement("p");
      if (data.results.length) {
        info.innerHTML = `Affichage de <strong>${data.results.length}</strong> sur <strong>${data.matches.length}</strong> résultat(s)`;
      } else {
        info.innerHTML = `Pas de résultats pour <strong>"${data.query}"</strong>`;
      }
      list.prepend(info);
    },
    noResults: true,
    maxResults: 15,
  },

  resultItem: {
    element: (item, data) => {
      // console.log(data.value.city + ' - ' + data.value.postcode + ' - ' + data.value.context);
            // Modify Results Item Style
            // item.style = "display: flex; justify-content: space-between;";
            // Modify Results Item Content
            item.innerHTML = `
      <span style="text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; color:#fe6000; font-weight: bold;">${data.value.city}</span><br>
      <span style="text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; font-size: 0.8em;">${data.value.postcode} - ${data.value.context}</span>`;
        },
  },

  events: {
    input: {
      selection: (event) => {
        const selection = event.detail.selection.value; // when clic send the name of the city in the input
        console.log('City coordinates : ' + selection.geometry.coordinates);
        sessionStorage.setItem('cityCoord', selection.geometry.coordinates);
        autoCompleteJS.input.value = selection.label;
      },
    },
  },
});
```

try search "frejus" and after try "fréjus", you see the problem ?

thx for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the option `diacritics` to `true`:

```js
const autoCompleteJS = new autoComplete({
  selector: '#location',
  // placeHolder: 'Recherchez une ville...',
  threshold: 3,
  diacritics: true,
```

Then when you type `frej` (without accent) it will be autocompleted.

[image]